# How do I make this script output: "Error connecting to Mom via SSH" when connection is down?

Tags: shell-script, error-handling, exit-status

## Intention

---

I am in the middle of writing a little shell script (POSIX, except for the `system_beep()`).

The script, which runs in Cygwin, should find out, if my mother's laptop is closed or not and give me clear result and if open also a 5x a beep.

## Code

---

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o nounset

blink=$(tput blink)
bold=$(tput bold)
reverse=$(tput rev)
no_color=$(tput sgr0)

red=$(tput setaf 1)
#blue=$(tput setaf 4)
#cyan=$(tput setaf 6)
green=$(tput setaf 2)
#white=$(tput setaf 7)
#yellow=$(tput setaf 3)
#magenta=$(tput setaf 5)

lid_open_color="${blink}${bold}${reverse}${red}"
lid_closed_color="${blink}${bold}${reverse}${green}"

system_beep()
{
    echo -ne '\007'
}

beep_x_times()
{
    i=1; while [ "$i" -le "$1" ]; do

        i=$((i + 1))
        system_beep
        sleep 1s

    done
}

get_lid_state_mom()
{
    if ! ssh heruser@laptop_ip -p port_number -o ConnectTimeout=3 -i /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa 2> /dev/null \
        cat /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state | awk '{print $2}'; then

#    if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then

        echo "Error connecting to Mom via SSH"
        exit 1

    fi

}

state=$(get_lid_state_mom)



if [ "$state" = "closed" ]; then

    echo "${lid_closed_color}closed${no_color}"

elif [ "$state" = "open" ]; then

    echo "${lid_open_color}open${no_color}"
    beep_x_times 5

else

    echo "Some error occurred!"

fi
```

---

## Problem

In spite of my efforts, I seem to be unable to understand why I get:

```
$ ./lid-status-mama-beep
Some error occurred!
```

While it behaves correctly, when the laptop is SSH connectable:

**If the lid is closed:**

```
$ ./lid-status-mama-beep
closed
```

**If the lid is open:**

```
$ ./lid-status-mama-beep
open
```

I obviously do something wrong in this error handling case.

---

## Question

How do I make this script output:

> ```
> Error connecting to Mom via SSH
> ```

when the connection is down for whatever reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

See comments for explanation on each line.

```
get_lid_state_mom()
{
    # I have omitted awk completely here, getting raw value instead
    ssh -p port_number -o ConnectTimeout=3 -i /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa heruser@laptop_ip cat /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state 2> /dev/null
}

# this had to be renamed in order for me to know it is a raw value
lid_state_raw=$(get_lid_state_mom)

# indirect test for successful execution seems to be the best method
if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then

    echo "Error connecting to Mom via SSH"
    exit 1

fi

# after the success extract the state from the raw value
lid_state=$(echo "$lid_state_raw" | awk '{print $2}')
```

Answer (score 0):

## Reason

Your if statement in `get_lid_state_mom` is wrong.

In the following code snippet, you can see that only the exit value of `second_command` is taken in account.

```
if ! first_command | second_command ; then 
    echo "second_command exited false"
fi
```

The `!` inverts the result of all `first_command | second_command`, so it is equivalent to `! second_command`

In your code second_command is the call to `awk`, so your `if` is true only when awk fails.